# Regular Expression for Swagger3 in java. Allowed string with comma separated value

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot, swagger-editor, swagger-3.0

I was trying to write regular expression for string variable in swagger3(OAS).

The string can have multiple comma separated string. Each string's length can be between 5 and 15 and each character in a string can be either a-z or A-Z or 0-9.

I tried this one **[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}**. This one does not work as expected

For example
Valid String eg

1. 3OMYJF5V11MJL,3OMYJF5V11MOP
2. 3OMYJF,3OMYJim,3OMYJF090

Invalid eg:

1. ??
2. 123
3. 123456789098765432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15})*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}` Match 5-15 chars in the range a-zA-Z0-9
- `(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15})*` Optionally repeat `,` and again 5-15 chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q8ISfS/1)